# error while using re.findall() to find all letters from A to Z

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

My code is:

```
import re
key, val = '  ', 2
  self._l[key] = re.findall(r"[A-Z]+", val)
```

Error:

```
return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: ...So which part of the error message is unclear?

Comment: sorry, I'm a beginner at programming. a small change did the work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `val` in your question is an `int`. If you set it to a `str` object, it would work:

```
>>> val = 2
>>> type(val)
<type 'int'>

>>> val = "2"
>>> type(val)
<type 'str'>
>>> re.findall(r"[A-Z]+", val)
[]

>>> val = 'SOME 123 STRING'
>>> re.findall(r"[A-Z]+", val)
['SOME', 'STRING']
```